# Unable to upload Category Thumbnail and Category Hover thumnail image

Tags: magento2, category

I am uploading the Category thumbnail image and category hover thumbnail image, but after saving the configuration both image links seems broken.
[image: screenshot after uploading]

when i am clicking on the link, its not correct, it is like 
[image]

i can see that the directory path is repeating itself, so , kindly help

Comment: try run all command after apply permission command

Comment: thanks for the time, but if you can eloborate a little more, @MohitPatel

Comment: go to command line and run `1)php bin/magento s:up 2)php bin/magento s:s:d -f 3)php bin/magento c:c 4)php bin/magento c:f` and apply permission this link--- https://magehit.com/blog/magento-2-file-folder-permissions-setting/

Comment: there is some issues, i ran al the coomands mentioned in magehit.com/blog/magento-2-file-folder-permissions-setting but now the site is not loading. autoload error

Comment: run composer update command

Comment: its asks for username, well i guessed its username and password so provided it, ran the command, but still the same problem, autoupload error

Comment: http://prntscr.com/sl9gum

Comment: connect to my skype i will explain more